Cloudfront appears to be blocking POST request
I am running a static website on an S3 bucket. The website has a form component, which sends a POST request to a back-end running on an EC2 server. When I submit the form everything works as it should when I access the website through the S3 bucket's URL, but when I use the website's URL which I have linked through CloudFront, the POST request does not get sent.
I have already changed permissions to allow POST etc. in the CloudFront distribution, and I am at a loss for further ideas.

Can you share details about any potential errors or HTTP status code errors you might be getting in the browser?
